# Inconsistent actions offered to moderators for flagged comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I noticed a moderator flag on the "action bar" and visited the page to see what it was, see image:

[image: Flagged report]

You will notice that there are three possible actions for this report flagged as "not an answer":

- Convert to comment
- No further action ...
- Delete answer

Plus, presumably, I can ignore the report altogether.

---

Now before choosing one of the above I click on the link to visit the problem page. At the bottom of the page a "pop-up" box appears, overlaying the bottom of the question/answer page, like this:

[image: Pop-up box]

Suddenly there are only two actions:

- No action needed ...
- Close

---

Why do the other two actions that could be taken on this answer not appear, like this (made-up example):

[image: Suggested fix]

It seems inconsistent that on one page you can do four things (if you count doing nothing) and on the other page you can do two things.

Whatever arguments there might be for having three buttons, or one button, or some other thing, surely they should at least be consistent?

Answer (score 10):

On the page itself, the other two actions live in the links directly below the answer:

[image]

- **Delete answer** appears directly below the post
- **Convert to comment** appears in the mod menu (which is directly below the post)

Because the bar is fixed at the bottom of the page, it would be difficult to ensure you were looking at the correct answer when viewing these options. An alternate UI might display the flag directly below the answer, which would then allow these "quick actions" to be displayed next to it - however, such a thing has not yet been implemented.